# Alfresco permissions see list of node content but deny download

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

Is it possible to set up a `permissionsDefinition.xml` in alfresco that is not allowing `GROUP_USERS` to download files but see the list of content?

I've tried to set the config like this in the .xml file.

This is the original definition of the `Read` permission group:

```
<permissionGroup name="Read"  expose="true" allowFullControl="false">
    <includePermissionGroup type="sys:base" permissionGroup="ReadProperties"/>
    <includePermissionGroup type="sys:base" permissionGroup="ReadChildren"/>
    <includePermissionGroup type="sys:base" permissionGroup="ReadContent"/>
</permissionGroup>
```

So the simple try was to just remove the permission to ReadContent, and change the group to this:

```
<permissionGroup name="Read"  expose="true" allowFullControl="false">
     <includePermissionGroup type="sys:base" permissionGroup="ReadProperties"/>
     <includePermissionGroup type="sys:base" permissionGroup="ReadChildren"/>
</permissionGroup>
```

According to this I created a new permissionGroup, like this:

```
<permissionGroup name="Reader" allowFullControl="false" expose="true" >
     <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="Read" type="sys:base" />
     <includePermissionGroup type="sys:base" permissionGroup="ReadPermissions"/>      
 </permissionGroup>
```

And later this group was included twice, once in `<permissionSet type="cm:content"/>` and `<permissionSet type="cm:folder"/>`.

To test this I broke inheritence of the space and parent folder and created a new user who is only member of `GROUP_USERS` with the permission of `reader`.

### The actual problem

While I can see the documents in query results I am not able to get an instance of the object with session.getObject(id). I always get an `CmisRuntimeException` with `Message: Object Info is missing`. As soon as I add ReadContent permission again, I am again able to get the object by Id.

So in order to get an instance of the object, I need to permit ReadContent, even I just want to get an instance of the object for read only tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to the documentation  [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/secur-acl-modifying.html)

> When modifying access control, do not try to split ReadProperties and ReadContent. This does not make sense for search. A node and all of its properties, including content, are indexed as one entity. Splitting the evaluation of access for content and properties is not possible. Search would have to apply both criteria so as to not leak information. Other services, such as copy, may not behave as expected or may produce nodes in an odd state.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But is there any other to separate all this permissions from the permission to download content?

Comment: I don't think there is a permission specific for downloading, I'm guessing if the user can read the document (content and properties) then he can download it. Do you use share? if yes I can explain how to hide/display the download action based on a evaluator to filter only users in the GROUP_USERS.

Comment: Sam, this is a very nice offer. Thank you again for your feedback :). We have build a little custom viewer, so Share will not be an option. From your reply I assume the answer for now is to "block" the downloading on application level. Not ideal but for the first draft this should be Ok. Have a fantastic day and thanks again.